# two datepickers inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, onclicklistener

I have a fragment and two EditTexts in my xml layout. The EditTexts should have a default value which is the current date. When I click on any of them, I want to show a datepicker from which I will be able to pick a date. After that, this date should be displayed on the EditText. The first EditText is my start date and the second is my end date. I want to create 2 datepicker listeners inside my fragment because I will validate the each selected date with in a different way. Does anybody know how to make two listeners for datepickers each one for each EditText? Thank you very much in advance. (if you have any questions or details just ask, I realy need help as fast as possible)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only using the EditText to display the date value I would recommend [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) instead.

To have a DatePicker display when you tap on them set an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) on your TextView to open a custom [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html) with a DatePicker inside.

You can read about dialogs in Android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)